# Why is Sympy unable to denest this expression?

Tags: python, sympy

Sympy seems unable to simplify the second power expression below (although it is able to simplify the first one). Is this a limitation of Sympy?

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x')
a = sp.symbols('a')
print(sp.powdenest((x**((a - 1)/a))**(a/(a - 1)), force=True))
print(sp.powdenest((x**(a/(a - 1)))**((a - 1)/a), force=True))
```

returns

```
x
(x**(a/(a - 1)))**((a - 1)/a)
```

Comment: `print(sp.powdenest(((x**(a/(a - 1)))**((a - 1)/a)).subs(a, b+1), force=True))`  does simplify. It must be some fear of negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why wouldn't this fear for negative numbers affect the first example too? Also, shouldn't setting `force=True` avoid any such fear?